# Good way for user to input NSNumbers into a variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm making an app for my football club to make little bets with each other. I'm trying to find a way of receiving a price input from a user. I need the number to be in a form of `N(X).XX` where it doesn't matter how many X's go before the decimal point. I've thought about a couple of options but I'm just not experienced enough to decide which is the best.

What I've thought about so far:

1. Create a text field which shows the number keypad. Then I can use `[numberFormatter numberFromString: text];`. However this seems a bit too risky. For instance, if the user were to type in `XX.XXX` or `X.XX.X` or something similar, then the app would accept those values, causing problems later on along the line.
2. The other idea I had was to use some sort of picker, but then we'll be limited to a fixed set of values.

What do you recommend? I'd probably use the text field with some sort of check for the correct format input, but I'm not entirely sure how I'd go about doing that.

**EDIT**: Just checked the eBay app, and they have a really nice way of doing it. They use a text field that limits to two digits after the decimal point. How on earth would I program that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on @SteveC's correct answer, some additional checks are required to limit not only the number of digits after the decimal point; but the number of decimal points (as you mentioned in the original question.):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([string length] == 0)
        return YES;
    NSInteger firstDecimalLocation = [[textField text] rangeOfString:@"."].location;
    if( firstDecimalLocation != NSNotFound ) {
        if( [string isEqualToString:@"."] ) {
            return NO;
        }
        if( firstDecimalLocation == range.location - 3 ) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    NSMutableCharacterSet *_alnum = [NSMutableCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"."];

    NSCharacterSet *numberSet = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
    [_alnum formUnionWithCharacterSet:numberSet];
    NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [_alnum invertedSet];


    return ([string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet].length > 0);
}
```

Note that this presumes you are using a `UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation`, rather than test for it in the `UITextFieldDelegate` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm going to implement this now. Regards, Mike

Comment: Worked fantastically. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yea I gave him a +1 earlier.

Comment: This won't work in locales that use a decimal separator other than the period. Many use the comma. Other places may use something else.

Comment: @rmaddy, I have just discovered this. How would I get around that?

Comment: What I do in my code is create an `NSNumberFormatter` and then get its `decimalSeparator` value. I then use that value in the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method instead of the hardcoded `@"."` literal.

Comment: @rmaddy This is such a fantastic fix. Really appreciate it, I never would have thought to do anything like that! I'll go mark up all your comments on this question to give you the rep you deserve.

Answer (score 2):

The number pad doesn't have a ".". 
In a similar situation I used the Numbers and Punctuation keyboard and had to implement the UITextFieldDelegate method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

There I blocked any character that isn't numeric or a "."

My code is as follows.  The idea came from another answer on stackoverflow but I can't find it right now so kudos to whoever provided that.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([string length] == 0)
        return YES;

    if ([textField keyboardType]==UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation)
    {
        NSMutableCharacterSet *_alnum = [NSMutableCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"."];

        NSCharacterSet *numberSet = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
        [_alnum formUnionWithCharacterSet:numberSet];
        NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [_alnum invertedSet];

        return ([string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet].length > 0);
    }else{
        return YES;
    }
}
```

In this same method in a similar way you could check textField.text to see how many digits there were after the decimal point and block any more being entered

Comment: Thanks for the reply really useful. The Decimal pad seems to be perfect for what I need. So I'll use the delegate method `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` to limit the number of characters after the decimal point.

Comment: Set the keyboard type to `UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad`. This include the . (or the , depending on the locale). BTW - having your validation only look for @"." is bad practice since it doesn't handle all of the locales that use a comma or other character.

Comment: Forgot to mention - even with the decimal pad, you still need to validate the input because someone might be using a wireless keyboard with their iOS device.